# How to automaticly refresh silverlight pages after deploy server services

Tags: c#, silverlight, deployment, version, ria

Firs of all sorry for my bad English.

I have an Silverlight application. And there is too much customer who is using my application.

When i deploy new version i see same problem.
As we know lots of time users opening any silverlight window and do not any request in a long time. İf I deploy my projects to server after user open window and user will request after deploy *httpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer* error is occuring.

How can i learn is service version changed before request and refresh client page automaticly.

I add an timer to App.xaml and requesting to server every 5 minutes. İf server deployed *httpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer* error is occuring. And i catcing this exception then showing warning message to user.
But i can not trust this way.

What is the best way to solve this problem.

Thans.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know to automatically refresh your Siverlight page is to manage the assembly version of your xap (which is a good practice anyway): ie increase it for each release.

Silverlight will automatically download it if it does not match the server version.

You can change your assembly version in properties->Application->Assembly Information

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.1")]
```